# Is it possible to change SplashScreen background at runtime - or to change color visible when user resize app window?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

On Package.Appmanifest we can define SplashScreen background color that is used for:

1) SplashScreen background - pretty obvious

2) to fit the space between new window border and not (yet) resized content when user is resizing the app window

If you don't know what I am writing about under 2) - just run Xbox app (or any other written with UWP), grab window border and then quickly move the window border back and forward.

The problem is that I would like to have two separate colors for that. Color A for SplashScreen background and Color B that would be visible during this resize. Apparently they are the same colors by default.

Is there any way to declare different colors for this two places within the app or any way to change the SplashScreen background color at runtime (to have the Color A during launch time and then after app has already lunched I could override this color with Color B to get the behaviour I need)?

Comment: Did you look at [Extended Splash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen)?

Comment: if I understood it correctly it is only for displaying SplashScreen for extended period of time (not overriding it which could be useful) - and so does the example - shows the SplashScreen defined within Package.Appmanifest and then ExtendedSplashScreen

Comment: Extended Splash is derived from `Page` so you should be able to change Backgrounds, Add Visual States as Desired.

Comment: that is not what I want, changing page background does not change the color visible when resizing window

Comment: So far as I know, there is no method to change the SplashScreen background color at runtime.

Comment: The Extended Splash allows you to add a second splash screen. My plan is to have a generic one that every customer sees then a different extended splash screen for each customer.