# Is it impossible to change the splash screen at runtime in uwp?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

We'd like to show one splash screen for Customer A and one for Customer B.

According to a stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978006/is-it-possible-to-change-splashscreen-background-at-runtime-or-to-change-color), the splash screen can't be set at runtime, but I'd like to be sure.

I read an excellent article [here](http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1087) on how to do it using build configurations. The problem is that my colleagues and I don't have faith in this method (though it works in my test app). If the system is copying files at runtime, something could go wrong.

A colleague suggested I could switch the splash screen at runtime by packaging it up in a dll. Please can someone tell me if this is possible?

I think it might be possible to amend the Package.appxmanifest at runtime, but this could be very difficult and risky to implement. (Discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236755/windows-uwp-modify-appx-package-at-runtime).)

At the moment I have a separate Package.appxmanifest that I copy manually when I wish to switch from Customer A to Customer B. I think I'll have to carry on doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement an "extended splash screen" which is configurable by the app at runtime, here is the MSDN doc on how to do this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen

Comment: See as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201701/removing-splash-screen-from-uwp-app-in-fcu which indicates how to make a splash screen optional unless Windows decides to display it anyway.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. I've now got two splash screens. The first one can be generic for all customers. The second is customer-specific.